# "Ignore Wordlist" Not Functioning

Tags: solspace, supersearch

Super Search Version 2.2.1, Expression Engine Version 2.8.1

My expectation with the Super Search Ignore Wordlist is that if I put a word on the list, that the term will be ignored completely, as though it were dropped from the search string. In other words, if someone searched "books on construction", and "on" was on the Ignore Wordlist, the search results would appear as though the search query was "books construction".

Is this correct? If this is not correct, then what exactly does the Ignore Wordlist do? If what I described is how the Ignore Wordlist is supposed to function, then for whatever reason ours is not working.

Here is the {exp:super_search:results} portion of our search template:

```
    {exp:super_search:results
        channel="products"
        limit="12"
        show_future_entries="yes"
        use_ignore_word_list="yes"
        search_in="title|product_display_title|product_author|product_sku|product_isbn|product_hidden_search"
        search_words_within_words="yes"
        allow_repeats="no"
        paginate="bottom"
        fuzzy_distance="2"
        fuzzy_weighting="yes"
    }

        {if super_search_no_results}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>No results matched your query.</p>
            </div>
        {/if}

        {if super_search_total_results==1}
            {redirect="product/{url_title}"}
        {/if}

        {if count == 1 OR count == 4 OR count == 7 OR count == 10}

        <div class="ad-col m-bottom">
            <div class="row ">

        {/if}
                <div class="col-md-4 ad-small">
                    <div class="well bg-1 ad-col-height">
                        <h4><a class="inherit-hyperlink" href="{url_title_path=product}">{title}</a></h4>
                        <div class="row m-top">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <a href="{url_title_path=product}"><img class="img-responsive" src="{if product_thumbnail}{product_thumbnail}{if:else}/media/products/noi.jpg{/if}" alt="{title}"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                {if product_tag!="" AND product_tag != "None"}
                                    <p class="{product_tag}">{product_tag:label}</p>
                                {/if}                           
                                {if product_author}<p><small>By {product_author}</small></p>{/if}
                                <p>Product Code: {product_sku}
                                <br />Price: {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}{price}{/exp:store:product}
                                <br />{if product_binding != "Other"}{product_binding}{/if}</p>
                                <p><a href="{url_title_path=product}" class="btn btn-default">View Details</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.row -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 m-top">
                                {product_short_description}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.well -->
                </div><!-- /.ad-small -->

        {if count == 3 OR count == 6 OR count == 9 OR count == 12 OR count == total_results}
            </div><!-- /row -->
        </div>
        {/if}

        {paginate}

        <div class="text-center">
        {pagination_links}
        <ul class="pagination">
        {first_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">&laquo;</a></li>
        {/first_page}

        {previous_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">&lt;</a></li>
        {/previous_page}

        {page}
        <li {if current_page}class="active"{/if}><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} ">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
        {/page}

        {next_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">&gt;</a></li>
        {/next_page}

        {last_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">&raquo;</a></li>
        {/last_page}
        </ul>
        {/pagination_links}
        </div>

        {/paginate}

    {/exp:super_search:results}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this in a Keyword search? The Ignore Wordlist feature only works with Keyword searches, and will NOT work for any other searches performed on custom fields, etc. :)
http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/results/#use_ignore_word_list